# How can I match a list of items against keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lookup

This seems simple enough but I can't figure out what's wrong.

First I gather a list of all filenames in a directory matching a specific string:

```
import os
import glob
dl = glob.glob('dir/*abc*')
for f in dl:
    fn = os.path.basename(f)
```

So now I have a list of filenames `fn` which contain `"abc"`. All good so far.

What I want to do is go through this list of filenames, try and match them against a set of keys in a dictionary, and wherever there is a match, to print out the corresponding dictionary value for that matching key.

Here's what I did:

```
fn_dict = {"abc.txt": "val1", "abc123.txt": "val2", "def.txt": "val3"}
for i in fn:
    if i in fn_dict.keys():
        print(fn_dict.get(i))
    else:
        print("No match")
```

I would expect to get back `"val1"` and `"val2"` but instead I only get `"No match"` over and over.

Comment: Can I suggest in your minimal repoduction, hard code the values for variable fn. Then it will be possible for other people to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fn` should be a list, else it will be a string and dictionary part of your will loop though the single file name instead of all the file names in the directory matching the pattern

```
import os
import glob
dl = glob.glob('dir/*abc*')
fn = []
for f in dl:
    fn.append(os.path.basename(f))
```

OR using list comprehension

```
fn = [os.path.basename(f) for f in dl]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop you reassign you `fn` variable

```
for f in dl:
    fn = os.path.basename(f) # fn is string now, not a list
```

and then in your second `for` loop you go through `fn` variable, which is a string, so create an array and add `os.path.basename(i)` into it

```
fn = []
for f in dl:
    fn.append(os.path.basename(f))
```